# Are there ways to speed up this string fuzzy matching in Golang?

Tags: python, performance, csv, go

I have a piece of python code doing fuzzy matching which works very well and is pretty fast. For reference, it uses the following files:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/s-and-p-500-companies/master/data/constituents.csv
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nlintz/pyBros/master/sp500/sp500.csv

```
import csv
from fuzzywuzzy import process

def csv_reader(file, key):
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        return [row[key] for row in reader]

const_data = csv_reader("constituents.csv", "Name")
target_data = csv_reader("sp500.csv", "company")

with open('results_python.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ["name", "match_name", "match_score"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in const_data:
        match = process.extractOne(row, target_data)
        writer.writerow({'name': row, 'match_name': match[0],    'match_score': match[1]})
```

This is how it performs:

```
$ time ./fuzzy.py   
./fuzzy.py  19,90s user 0,13s system 97% cpu 20,444 total
```

However, my surprise came when I did a pretty similar code in Golang using a port of the `fuzzywuzzy` library. I want to understand if the slowness of it is related to the way I structure my code, or some deeper reason within the matching library.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "github.com/paul-mannino/go-fuzzywuzzy"
)

func readCsv(file string) [][]string {
    csvFile, _ := os.Open(file)
    defer csvFile.Close()
    r := csv.NewReader(csvFile)
    records, _ := r.ReadAll()
    return records
}

func main() {

    original:= readCsv("constituents.csv")
    target:= readCsv("sp500.csv")
    csvOut, _ := os.Create("results_go.csv")
    csvwriter := csv.NewWriter(csvOut)

    var targetData []string

    for _, line := range target[1:] {   
        targetData = append(targetData, line[1])
    }
    csvwriter.Write([]string{"name", "match_name", "match_score"})
    for _, line := range original[1:] {
        match, _ := fuzzy.ExtractOne(line[1], targetData)
        csvwriter.Write([]string{line[1], match.Match, strconv.Itoa(match.Score)})
    }
}
```

This is how the Go version performs:

```
$ time ./fuzzy   
./fuzzy 75,04s user 1,28s system 98% cpu 1:17,51 total
```

Are there any possible bad steps that I took in my Go code that made this comparison slow? Are there any improvements you could suggest to make it perform at the very least to a similar speed as the python code?

Comment: Do you want a review of the Python code?

Comment: I was hoping more for a review of the Go version, but if you have some comments about the Python version too, I would also appreciate them.

Answer (score 12):

**Review I - package `go-fuzzywuzzy`**

---

After a quick read of your Go code, the Go code for package `go-fuzzywuzzy`, and the Go documentation, it is reasonable to hope for at least a 60% to 95% improvement in Go performance.

---

For example,

```
$ go build fuzzy.go && time ./fuzzy
real    0m55.183s
user    0m58.858s
sys     0m0.944s
$
```

After moving one line in package `go-fuzzywuzzy`,

```
$ go build fuzzy.go && time ./fuzzy
real    0m6.321s
user    0m7.211s
sys     0m0.188s
$
```

The line to move:

```
r := regexp.MustCompile("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]")
```

A diff of package `go-fuzzywuzzy`:

```
diff --git a/stringutility.go b/stringutility.go
index 935f6e1..95441cc 100644
--- a/stringutility.go
+++ b/stringutility.go
@@ -5,6 +5,8 @@ import (
        "strings"
 )

+var rxCleanse = regexp.MustCompile("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]")
+
 func Cleanse(s string, forceAscii bool) string {
        s = strings.TrimSpace(s)
        s = strings.ToLower(s)
@@ -12,8 +14,7 @@ func Cleanse(s string, forceAscii bool) string {
                s = ASCIIOnly(s)
        }

-       r := regexp.MustCompile("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]")
-       s = r.ReplaceAllString(s, " ")
+       s = rxCleanse.ReplaceAllString(s, " ")
        return s
 }
```

---

> [Package regexp](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/)
>
> ```
>  import "regexp"
> ```
>
> [func MustCompile](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#MustCompile)
>
> ```
> func MustCompile(str string) *Regexp
> ```
>
> MustCompile is like Compile but panics if the expression cannot be
>   parsed. It simplifies safe initialization of global variables holding
>   compiled regular expressions.

The documentation clearly says **global** variables.

---

If I spent more time reading the code, I would expect further performance improvements.

---

---

After more reading, package `go-fuzzywuzzy` is written in "PyGo." Writing the package in Go yields efficiencies.

For example, completely rewriting the `go-fuzzywuzzy` file `stringutility.go` in Go.

Before:

```
$ go build fuzzy.go && time ./fuzzy
real    0m55.183s
user    0m58.858s
sys     0m0.944s
$
```

After:

```
$ go build fuzzy.go && time ./fuzzy
real    0m5.735s
user    0m6.601s
sys     0m0.193s
$
```

`stringutility.go`:

```
package fuzzy

import (
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

func Cleanse(s string, forceAscii bool) string {
    if forceAscii {
        s = ASCIIOnly(s)
    }
    s = strings.TrimSpace(s)
    rs := make([]rune, 0, len(s))
    for _, r := range s {
        if !unicode.IsLetter(r) && !unicode.IsNumber(r) {
            r = ' '
        }
        rs = append(rs, r)
    }
    return strings.ToLower(string(rs))
}

func ASCIIOnly(s string) string {
    b := make([]byte, 0, len(s))
    for _, r := range s {
        if r <= unicode.MaxASCII {
            b = append(b, byte(r))
        }
    }
    return string(b)
}
```

---

---

UPDATE:

The package `go-fuzzywuzzy` author adopted the suggested `stringutility.go` changes:

```
[Fixes #4] Stop reinitializing costly regex in stringutility
https://github.com/paul-mannino/go-fuzzywuzzy/commit/f14294bf5858c8a7fa51b026a9ee9a2802c816bf

Was using regexp.MustCompile within a frequently invoked
method Cleanse. Since go does not cache these calls, it was
incurring a costly regex compilation each time Cleanse was
called. The other changes made in the stackoverflow post that
caught this issue seem to further improve performance by
about 10% on top of the massive gains from fixing this issue,
so incorporating those as well.
```

Comment: You summarized the issues really well! I am just confused about something: What is PyGo?... Couldn't find any reference to it

Comment: I [reported the bad performance](https://github.com/paul-mannino/go-fuzzywuzzy/issues/4) to the author of go-fuzzywuzzy.

Comment: And, only 2 hours later, it's fixed, so after updating to the latest go-fuzzywuzzy, the original code should run quite fast.

Comment: @telex-wap: "PyGo" is a hybrid language used when converting Python code, with minimal changes, to compile as Go code. It is often unreadable and unmaintainable, and it often performs poorly.

Answer (score 3):

**Review II - your `fuzzy.go` code**

---

After a quick read of your Go code, the Go code for package `go-fuzzywuzzy`, and the Go documentation, it is reasonable to hope for at least a 60% to 95% improvement in Go performance.

---

Review I, package `go-fuzzywuzzy`, completely rewrote the package `go-fuzzywuzzy` file `stringutility.go` in Go for a significant improvement in performance.

Before:

```
$ go build fuzzy.go && time ./fuzzy
real    0m55.183s
user    0m58.858s
sys     0m0.944s
$
```

After:

```
$ go build fuzzy.go && time ./fuzzy
real    0m5.735s
user    0m6.601s
sys     0m0.193s
$
```

The package `go-fuzzywuzzy` author adopted the suggested `stringutility.go` changes:

```
[Fixes #4] Stop reinitializing costly regex in stringutility
https://github.com/paul-mannino/go-fuzzywuzzy/commit/f14294bf5858c8a7fa51b026a9ee9a2802c816bf

Was using regexp.MustCompile within a frequently invoked
method Cleanse. Since go does not cache these calls, it was
incurring a costly regex compilation each time Cleanse was
called. The other changes made in the stackoverflow post that
caught this issue seem to further improve performance by
about 10% on top of the massive gains from fixing this issue,
so incorporating those as well.
```

---

---

Now that poor package `go-fuzzywuzzy` performance is no longer muffling your code performance, let's review your code (`fuzzy.go`).

Fix obvious problems: check for errors, check for indices in range, flush buffers, close files, and so on.

Your fuzzy search algorithm performance appears to be quadratic - O(original x target). For many cases (exact lowercase match), replace your quadratic algorithm with a linear algorithm - O(original x 1).

```
for _, line := range original {
    // ...
    name, data := line[1], targetData
    if target, ok := targetMap[strings.ToLower(name)]; ok {
        data = []string{target}
    }
    match, err := fuzzy.ExtractOne(name, data)
    // ...
}
```

Performance:

```
$ go build fuzzy.go && time ./fuzzy
real    0m5.370s
user    0m6.228s
sys     0m0.175s
$

$ go build peter.go && time ./peter
real    0m2.372s
user    0m2.785s
sys     0m0.070s
$
```

Also, `peter.go` appears to be much faster than your Python implementation (`fuzzy.py`).

As promised, the Go user time has been improved by over 95%: original telex-wap 0m58.858s; peterSO 0m2.785s; user -95.27%.

`peter.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

    fuzzy "github.com/paul-mannino/go-fuzzywuzzy"
)

func readCsv(file string) ([][]string, error) {
    csvFile, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer csvFile.Close()
    r := csv.NewReader(csvFile)
    records, err := r.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return records, nil
}

func matchNames() error {
    target, err := readCsv("sp500.csv")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(target) > 1 {
        target = target[1:]
    }
    var targetData []string
    var targetMap = make(map[string]string, len(target))
    for _, line := range target {
        if len(line) <= 1 {
            continue
        }
        name := strings.TrimSpace(line[1])
        targetData = append(targetData, name)
        targetMap[strings.ToLower(name)] = name
    }

    original, err := readCsv("constituents.csv")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(original) > 1 {
        original = original[1:]
    }

    csvOut, err := os.Create("results_go.csv")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    csvWriter := csv.NewWriter(csvOut)
    err = csvWriter.Write([]string{"name", "match_name", "match_score"})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, line := range original {
        if len(line) <= 1 {
            continue
        }
        name, data := strings.TrimSpace(line[1]), targetData
        if target, ok := targetMap[strings.ToLower(name)]; ok {
            data = []string{target}
        }
        match, err := fuzzy.ExtractOne(name, data)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        err = csvWriter.Write([]string{name, match.Match, strconv.Itoa(match.Score)})
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    csvWriter.Flush()
    err = csvWriter.Error()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = csvOut.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := matchNames()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

`fuzzy.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "github.com/paul-mannino/go-fuzzywuzzy"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func readCsv(file string) [][]string {
    csvFile, _ := os.Open(file)
    defer csvFile.Close()
    r := csv.NewReader(csvFile)
    records, _ := r.ReadAll()
    return records
}

func main() {

    original := readCsv("constituents.csv")
    target := readCsv("sp500.csv")
    csvOut, _ := os.Create("results_go.csv")
    csvwriter := csv.NewWriter(csvOut)

    var targetData []string

    for _, line := range target[1:] {
        targetData = append(targetData, line[1])
    }
    csvwriter.Write([]string{"name", "match_name", "match_score"})
    for _, line := range original[1:] {
        match, _ := fuzzy.ExtractOne(line[1], targetData)
        csvwriter.Write([]string{line[1], match.Match, strconv.Itoa(match.Score)})
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It was very useful to read. I specially found interesting the detail with the quadratic algorithm. This is a task that I perform now and then, so this advice will help my future fuzzy coding style significantly!