# http router written in Golang

Tags: go, http, url-routing

in my jurney to learn Go, I decided to write a simple router which I called it [Gouter](https://github.com/smoqadam/gouter), which I think it has most of the features in gorilla/mux but in my opinion it's easier to use. Anyway, it consists of two file, `router.go` and `route.go`. There are some concerns I have about this. First about the performance and the second is, is it good enough to use it in production or not? and the finally how can I improve it.

Thanks

`router.go`

```
package router

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
)

type key int

const (
    contextKey key = iota
    varsKey
)

type Router struct {
    // Routes stores a collection of Route struct
    Routes []Route

    // ctx is an interface type will be accessible from http.request
    ctx    interface{}
}


// NewRouter return a new instance of Router
func NewRouter() *Router {
    return &Router{}
}

// GET register a GET request
func (r *Router) GET(path string, h http.HandlerFunc) *Route {
    return r.AddRoute(path, http.MethodGet, h)
}

// POST register a POST request
func (r *Router) POST(path string, h http.HandlerFunc) *Route {
    return r.AddRoute(path, http.MethodPost, h)
}

// PUT register a PUT request
func (r *Router) PUT(path string, h http.HandlerFunc) *Route {
    return r.AddRoute(path, http.MethodPut, h)
}

// PATCH register a PATCH request
func (r *Router) PATCH(path string, h http.HandlerFunc) *Route {
    return r.AddRoute(path, http.MethodPatch, h)
}

// DELETE register a DELETE request
func (r *Router) DELETE(path string, h http.HandlerFunc) *Route {
    return r.AddRoute(path, http.MethodDelete, h)
}

// AddRoute create a new Route and append it to Routes slice
func (r *Router) AddRoute(path string, method string, h http.HandlerFunc) *Route {
    route := NewRoute(path, method, h)
    r.Routes = append(r.Routes, route)
    return &route
}

// With send an interface along side the http.request.
// It is accessible with router.Context() function
func (r *Router) With(i interface{}) *Router {
    r.ctx = i
    return r
}

// ServeHTTP implement http.handler
func (r *Router) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    ctx := context.WithValue(req.Context(), contextKey, r.ctx)
    req = req.WithContext(ctx)

    var match *Route
    var h http.Handler
    for _, route := range r.Routes {
        if route.Match(req) {
            vars := route.extractVars(req)
            ctx := context.WithValue(req.Context(), varsKey, vars)
            req = req.WithContext(ctx)
            match = &route
            break
        }
    }

    if match != nil && match.method != req.Method {
        h = &MethodNotAllowed{}
    }

    if h == nil && match != nil {
        h = match.dispatch()
    }

    if match == nil || h == nil {
        h = http.NotFoundHandler()
    }

    h.ServeHTTP(w, req)
}

// Vars return a map of variables defined on the route.
func Vars(req *http.Request) map[string]string {
    if v := req.Context().Value(varsKey); v != nil {
        return v.(map[string]string)
    }
    return nil
}

func Context(req *http.Request) interface{} {
    if v := req.Context().Value(contextKey); v != nil {
        return v
    }
    return nil
}
```

and the `route.go`:

```
package router

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

type Middleware func(handler http.Handler) http.Handler

type Route struct {
    path    string
    name    string
    handler http.Handler
    method  string
    mw      []Middleware
    where   map[string]string
    vars    map[string]string
}

// NewRoute create a new route
func NewRoute(path string, method string, handler http.HandlerFunc) Route {
    return Route{
        path:    path,
        handler: handler,
        method:  method,
        vars:    make(map[string]string),
        where:   make(map[string]string),
    }
}

// Name assign a name for the route
func (r *Route) Name(s string) *Route {
    r.name = s
    return r
}

// Match return true if the requested path would match with the current route path
func (r *Route) Match(req *http.Request) bool {
    regex := regexp.MustCompile(`{([^}]*)}`)
    matches := regex.FindAllStringSubmatch(r.path, -1)
    p := r.path
    for _, v := range matches {
        s := fmt.Sprintf("{%s}", v[1])
        p = strings.Replace(p, s, r.where[v[1]], -1)
    }
    regex, err := regexp.Compile(p)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }
    matches = regex.FindAllStringSubmatch(req.URL.Path, -1)
    for _, match := range matches {

        if regex.Match([]byte(match[0])) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func (r *Route) clear(s string) string {
    s = strings.Replace(s, "{", "", -1)
    s = strings.Replace(s, "}", "", -1)
    return s
}

// Where define a regex pattern for the variables in the route path
func (r *Route) Where(key string, pattern string) *Route {
    r.where[key] = fmt.Sprintf("(%s)", pattern)
    return r
}

// Middleware register a collection of middleware functions and sort them
func (r *Route) Middleware(mw ...Middleware) *Route {
    r.mw = mw

    //TODO: Fix this
    for i := len(r.mw)/2 - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        opp := len(r.mw) - 1 - i
        r.mw[i], r.mw[opp] = r.mw[opp], r.mw[i]
    }
    return r
}

// extractVars parse the requested URL and return key/value pair of
// variables defined in the route path.
func (r *Route) extractVars(req *http.Request) map[string]string {
    url := strings.Split(req.URL.Path, "/")
    path := strings.Split(r.clear(r.path), "/")
    vars := make(map[string]string)
    for i := 0; i < len(url); i++ {
        if _, ok := r.where[path[i]]; ok {
            vars[path[i]] = url[i]
        }
    }
    return vars
}

// dispatch run route middleswares if any then run the route handler
func (r *Route) dispatch() http.Handler {
    for _, m := range r.mw {
        r.handler = m(r.handler)
    }
    return r.handler
}
```

### How to use it:

```
func main() {
  r := router.NewRouter()

  r.GET("/user/{user}", userHandler).
      Name("index").
      Where("user", "[a-z0-9]+").
      Middleware(mid1)

  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r)
}

func userHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   vars := router.Vars(r)
   fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello, %s!", vars["user"])
}

func mid1(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
      fmt.Println("from middleware 1")
      next.ServeHTTP(w, r) // call another middleware or the final handler
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You write:

```
func (r *Route) Match(req *http.Request) bool {
    regex := regexp.MustCompile(`{([^}]*)}`)
    // ...
}
```

Therefore, we would expect your performance to be poor.

See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236196/13970

What performance testing have you done? Where are your benchmarks?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't done any benchmark but I think the regex in Go is slow and it's not specific to `MustCompile` function. right? Do you have any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: @SaeedM.: In my answer I gave you a link to an earlier answer which explained the problem and how to solve it by moving a line.